# Autosar - pdur - module responsible to trigger event type pdu

Tags: serial-port, autosar, pdu

Can someone explain which module is responsible to trigger event type pdu?

Answer (score 0):

users of PDUR e.g., COM, DCM, BSWM which in turn can trigger based on application triggers e.g., related PDU's COM signal or signal group is triggered by Application through data mapping interface to COM.